# CakePHP: Setting up relationship between two models via a third table

Tags: model-view-controller, database-design, cakephp, model

I have the following tables:

- Users
- Organizations
- Email_Addresses
- Email_Address_Relations

Both Users and Organizations may have email addresses, which are stored in the Email_Addresses table and related to via the Email_Address_Relations table.

**Structure of Email_Address_Relations**

```
id char(36) NOT NULL
module varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'User'
record_id char(36) NOT NULL
email_address_id  char(36) NOT NULL
created datetime NOT NULL
modified datetime NOT NULL
```

My idea is to indicate the type of the email address (User or Organization) using a suitable value in the **module** field. The **record_id** and **email_address_id** fields will map the correct email address from the Email_Addresses to it's owner user or organization.

How do I go about setting up such a model in CakePHP?

Thanks,
m^e

---

To answer my last comment on setting up the models to provide default values for the **module** field, **YES, it can be done** as I [found out from CakePHP Forums](http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/setting_up_relationship_between_two_models_via_a_third_table).

This is how it is done.

```
class User extends AppModel {
  var $hasMany = array(
    'EmailAddress' => array(
      'className' => 'EmailAddress',
      'foreignKey' => 'record_id',
      'conditions' => array(
        'EmailAddress.module' => 'User'
      )
    )
  );
}

class Organization extends AppModel {
  var $hasMany = array(
    'EmailAddress' => array(
      'className' => 'EmailAddress',
      'foreignKey' => 'record_id',
      'conditions' => array(
        'EmailAddress.module' => 'Organization'
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need both `Email_Addresses` and `Email_Address_Relations` tables? I would go about it differently and just set up the `Email_Addresses` table. Like that:

```
id
module_id (record_id)
module
email_address
created
modified
```

And then both `Users` and `Organizations` hasMany `Email_Addresses` through `module_id`, and `Email_Addresses` belongsTo `Users` and `Organizations`.

Comment: Errrm.. Thanks I guess for making me feel ultra silly :D Sometimes when you think too hard this is what happens to you.. lol. Yep! Your way makes it much simpler. Cheers.

Comment: Follow-up question on this.. Is there a way I can setup a default value for the "module" field in the models of User and Organization so that User's relation to Email_Addresses will always use the string "User" for module and likewise Organization will use "Org"...

Comment: Don't think so, can't think of a way to achieve this.

Comment: Yep. It can be done as I found out from Cake forums. Please check the question above - I've added the solution in there. Thanks for your help :)